# Store checkboxes data from php to database

Tags: php, database, checkbox

I have the following tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE users_subjects (
  users_subjects_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id_fk int(11),
  subject_id_fk int(11),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(subject_id_fk) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (users_subjects_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

In the table 'users_subjects' I’m trying to relate the 'subjects' and 'users' tables.
All the data in the tables are entered from my index.php.

I introduce the subject_name from my index.php and every time I enter a new one, checkboxes like these are created in the part where the user is added:

[image]

This is the code to enter the user, where checkboxes are formed every time a subject is introduced (index.php):

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>User</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Subjects</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT subject FROM subjects"; /*Select from table name: subjects*/
        $result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
        if($result)
        {
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='subject' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "' /> <label>" . $row['subject'] . " </label><br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Add new user</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have managed to enter the user name in the 'users' table.

The problem I have is that I don’t know how to shore the checkboxes data in the 'users_subjects' table. I'm stuck and I can’t get it solved. Can somebody help me?

This is the code I’ve done for ‘register.php’:

```
<?php
$username = "";
$subject = "";
$errors = array();

include('Conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject']);


    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($subject)) { array_push($errors, "Subject is required"); }

    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) { // if user exists
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }
    }
    // Register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username) 
           VALUES('$username')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);


        $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $subject=implode(',',$_POST['subject']);
        //Count subjects and checks if the subject exists
        for($i=0; $i<count($subject); $i++) {

            $query = "SELECT subject_id FROM subject where subject='$subject[$i]'";
            $result = $conn->query($query); /*Check connection*/

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $subject_id = $row["subject_id"];
                $query = "INSERT INTO users_subjects (user_id_fk, subject_id_fk)
           VALUES('$insert_id', '$subject_id')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            } else {
                /*???*/
            }
        }



        header('location: indexAdmin.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Only problem I see is that `subject='$subject[$i]'` needs to be `subject='{$subject[$i]}'`. I would also do a `var_dump` on `$subject` to verify that it contains the keys/values that you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is right here:

```
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='subject' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "' /> <label>" . $row['subject'] . " </label><br>";
        }
```

When using checkboxes with the same name, you need to treat them as an array.  Look at this:

```
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "' /> <label>" . $row['subject'] . " </label><br>";
        }
```

By changing the "name=" to "subject[]", php will store the selected values into an array:

```
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

At this point, $subject will be an array containing the value of every clicked box.  (Please dont forget to do proper due diligence and validate this data.  That is beyond the scope of your question, but I did want to mention it).

If you want to just store the array in the database, you will want to "serialize()" the array.  That will take your array variable and convert it into a string that represents an array.   You can then store that string into your DB, and when you read the db you can "unserialize()" the string back into an array.  You can also just take the array and make a comma delimited list using implode.

For example:

To make the array into a string:

```
$str = serialize($subject);
```

To turn the serialized string back into an array:

```
$arrSubject = unserialize($str);
```

Or to take the array and put it into a comma-delimited string to store it that way:

```
$str = implode(", ", $subject);
```

And some links:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Have fun :)

Comment: You would need to convert `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject']);` to a `foreach($_POST['subject'], as &$subject){ $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $subject); }`, since it will error on an array (array to string conversion) But I strongly recommend instead to use a prepared statement instead of escaping.

Comment: True, I was cut and pasting his example.  I'll edit my response to be a little more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! very well explained :D

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

as you say : The problem I have is that I don’t know how to shore the checkboxes data in the 'users_subjects' table" you could create another text type field and keep the values ​​in JSON format where the key and the type of checkbox and the value is true or false depending on whether the checkbox is flagged or not.
es. {sat:true,ICT:false,subject:false}